# Problem with minio on docker container (File access denied=

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, ubuntu, minio

I'm trying to get the docker container to run but there is an error with minio.
The project is a web application with React for the Frontend and Ruby on Rails for the Backend. Database is a MySQL database.
I'm not sure what this problem exactly is. It seems like it cannot rename / create a file because the access is denied. Is this problem coming from my local machine?

Here is the log

```
Attaching to deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1, deep_path_finder_rails_api-cache-1, deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1, deep_path_finder_rails_api-init-minio-1, deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1, deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11 23:15:34+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1debian11 started.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |  23:15:34.57 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |  23:15:34.58 Welcome to the Bitnami minio container
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |  23:15:34.58 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |  23:15:34.58 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |  23:15:34.58 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11 23:15:34+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11 23:15:34+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1debian11 started.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:34 Waiting for: tcp://db:3306
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:34 Problem with dial: dial tcp 172.18.0.3:3306: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | API: SYSTEM()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | Time: 14:15:34 UTC 12/11/2023
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | Error: unable to rename (/data/.minio.sys/tmp -> /data/.minio.sys/tmp-old/2e24cf7c-a0ec-42bc-9333-3eaaa6856e96) file access denied, drive may be faulty please investigate (*fmt.wrapError)
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        6: internal/logger/logger.go:258:logger.LogIf()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        5: cmd/prepare-storage.go:88:cmd.bgFormatErasureCleanupTmp()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        4: cmd/xl-storage.go:250:cmd.newXLStorage()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        3: cmd/object-api-common.go:61:cmd.newStorageAPI()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        2: cmd/format-erasure.go:673:cmd.initStorageDisksWithErrors.func1()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        1: internal/sync/errgroup/errgroup.go:123:errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | API: SYSTEM()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | Time: 14:15:34 UTC 12/11/2023
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | Error: unable to create (/data/.minio.sys/tmp) file access denied, drive may be faulty please investigate (*fmt.wrapError)
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        6: internal/logger/logger.go:258:logger.LogIf()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        5: cmd/prepare-storage.go:95:cmd.bgFormatErasureCleanupTmp()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        4: cmd/xl-storage.go:250:cmd.newXLStorage()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        3: cmd/object-api-common.go:61:cmd.newStorageAPI()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        2: cmd/format-erasure.go:673:cmd.initStorageDisksWithErrors.func1()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       |        1: internal/sync/errgroup/errgroup.go:123:errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1()
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | ERROR Unable to use the drive /data: drive access denied: Invalid arguments specified
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1       | 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11T14:15:35.015518Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11T14:15:35.015771Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11T14:15:35.023861Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-init-minio-1  | mc: <ERROR> Unable to initialize new alias from the provided credentials. Get "http://minio:9000/probe-bsign-tjvm199pdaa3mzmh6oyrbdb3v2qnpq/?location=": dial tcp 172.18.0.4:9000: connect: connection refused.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-init-minio-1  | Bucket created successfully `minio/deep-path-finder-s3-development`.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11T14:15:35.155428Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11T14:15:35.437106Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11T14:15:35.437209Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11T14:15:35.442098Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11T14:15:35.493899Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | 2023-12-11T14:15:35.494319Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
deep_path_finder_rails_api-init-minio-1 exited with code 0
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: using the "epoll" event method
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: nginx/1.24.0
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: OS: Linux 6.1.0-1027-oem
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:524288
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker processes
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 24
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 25
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 26
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 27
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 28
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 29
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 30
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 31
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 32
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 33
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 34
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 35
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 36
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 37
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 38
deep_path_finder_rails_api-web-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 39
deep_path_finder_rails_api-minio-1 exited with code 1
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | 2023/12/11 23:15:35 Connected to tcp://db:3306
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | Database 'deep_path_finder_rails_api_development' already exists
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | Database 'deep_path_finder_rails_api_test' already exists
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | mbind: Operation not permitted
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | mbind: Operation not permitted
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | mbind: Operation not permitted
deep_path_finder_rails_api-db-1          | mbind: Operation not permitted
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | => Booting Puma
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | => Rails 7.0.4.2 application starting in local_development 
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | Puma starting in single mode...
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | * Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.2.0-p0) ("Birdie's Version")
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | *  Min threads: 5
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | *  Max threads: 5
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | *  Environment: local_development
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | *          PID: 14
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3001
deep_path_finder_rails_api-api-1         | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

The person who is in charge for this project also don't know what error this is because on his machine he could run the Docker container...
Am I missing something like credentials or permission?

Comment: It would help to know your docker-compose file

Comment: are you using `MINIO_USERNAME` and `MINIO_GROUPNAME` in your docker-compose.yaml file. Please share your dokcer-compose file so that we can help.